# mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'databasename' when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, localhost, dump, access-denied

when I use the command `mysqldump -u user -p my_db > my_db.sql`
I could dump one database, same time I couldn't dump the other database on MySQL server.it shows the error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'my_db' when using LOCK TABLES
```

how this happen??

Answer (score 1):

use the same mysqldump command, simply adding the `--single-transaction flag`, eg. `mysqldump --single-transaction -u dbuser -p my_db > my_db.sql --set-gtid-purged=OFF`